# Using a 'one key to many values' entry in SQLite3 database with Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a text file that contains many different entries.  What I'd like to do is take the first column, use each unique value as a key, and then store the second column as values.  I actually have this working, sort of, but I'm looking for a better way to do this.  Here is my example file:

```
account_check:"login/auth/broken"
adobe_air_installed:kb_base+"/"+app_name+"/Path"
adobe_air_installed:kb_base+"/"+app_name+"/Version"
adobe_audition_installed:'SMB/Adobe_Audition/'+version+'/Path'
adobe_audition_installed:'SMB/Adobe_Audition/'+version+'/ExePath'
```

Here is the code I'm using to parse my text file:

```
val_dict = {}

for row in creader:
    try:
        value = val_dict[row[0]]
        value += row[1] + ", "
    except KeyError:
        value = row[1] + ", "
    val_dict[row[0]] = value

for row in val_dict.items():
    values = row[1][:-1],row[0]
    cursor.execute("UPDATE 'plugins' SET 'sets_kb_item'= ? WHERE filename= ?", values)
```

And here is the code I use to query + format the data currently:

```
def kb_item(query):
    db = get_db()
    cur = db.execute("select * from plugins where sets_kb_item like ?", (query,))
    plugins = cur.fetchall()
    for item in plugins:
        for i in item['sets_kb_item'].split(','):
            print i.strip()
```

Here is the output:

```
kb_base+"/Installed"
kb_base+"/Path"
kb_base+"/Version"
```

It took me many tries but I finally got the output the way I wanted it, however I'm looking for critique.  Is there a better way to do this?  Could my entire `for item in plugins.... print i.strip()` be done in one line and saved as a variable?  I am very new to working with databases, and my python skills could also use refreshing.

*NOTE* I'm using csvreader in this code because I originally had a .csv file - however I found it was just as easy to use the .txt file I was provided.

Comment: I recommend you use an ORM like sqlite or peewee ... also provide a more minimal code example ... as it is I cant get past wall of text to  even tell what your doing

Comment: Sorry - I just wanted to provide as much detail as I could, but I can see how this is a rather large wall of text.